# I have two different clash of clans accounts on the same email

Tags: clash-of-clans

Me and my sister made two different clash of clans accounts on the same google account by mistake. How can we separate them without losing them both ? I should mention that my sister lost her phone so she can't log in to her village.

Answer (score 3):

I think only Supercell can help you. In the game go to *settings*, *help and support*, and then the 2nd option (lost village or something like that, it shows up in Dutch here). They were very helpful when I had the same problem.